# Rebuild Index progress dialog shows Sitecore Desktop

Tags: indexing

In Sitecore 8.2 Update 3, when I try and rebuild an index from inside the content editor (From the Developer ribbon) when the dialog opens that should be a progress bar showing the rebuilding progress, instead I get a little desktop:

[image]

I dont see an error in the logs but I do see in the logs that the index rebuild is happening. If I close the dialog, I get the index rebuilt successfully confirmation dialog.

**UPDATE**

When I make the rebuild request, there are two outgoing requests. The second one is checking progress. The first one is maybe opening the dialog?

https://local.mywebsite.com/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=Gallery.Indexes&id=%7B110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9%7D&la=en&vs=1&db=master&sc_content=master&ShowEditor=1&Ribbon.RenderTabs=true

And this one check the progress
 https://local.mywensite.com/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Progress.aspx?j=69195195-7797-40c5-be86-953b862b53d1%3bPHLWLTPC0J7N3W-local.aramark.us&th=5&title=Rebuilding%2bindex%2b(frontendsearch_UnitedStates_web_index)&i=People%252f16x16%252fhammer.png

Comment: Open the chrome devs tools, in the navigation tab do you see the request going out for the iframe. What is the url its requesting and what is the response?

Comment: I don't have that specific version of Sitecore installed but this looks like a bug. I would raise support ticket to Sitecore Support

Answer (score 1):

OK. Found the problem. During a scan of the site I found a bunch of links like this:

https://local.mywebsite.com/other/contact-us/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/~/link.aspx?_id=B727B5BE173F4423924C17C19278C0E0&_z=z

So I built a redirect rule to strip those out:

```
  <rule name="Expanded Links" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".+?(?=~\/)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" logRewrittenUrl="true" url="{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
```

That rules breaks the dialog